# How to identify nested routes in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to define nested routes in my application using react-router-dom. Here is that I have:The problem is that all routes work fine except those defined in the App.js. What needs to be done to make all routes work?

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/app" component={App} />
      <Route path="/smartphones" component={() => <SmartphoneTable smartphones={PHONES} />} />
      <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm} />
      <Route component={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      welcome: "you!"
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Jumbotron>
          <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}, {this.props.age} y.o.!</h1>
          <p>{this.state.welcome}</p>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/app/clock" component={() => <Clock interval="2000" />} />
            <Route path="/app/button" component={() => <ClickButton class="off" label="Press me" />} />
          </Switch>
        </Jumbotron>
      </Container>
    );
```

Comment: Could you give us an idea of the desired page flow? I'm not sure it's clear what your desired outcome is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.js` remove the `exact` prop:

```
<Route path="/app" component={App} />
```

Everytime `path` changes to `/app/foo` App gets unmounted therefore unmounting the children.